# Limiting Distribution of $\left(\prod\limits_{i=1}^{n} U_i\right)^{1/n}$ with $(U_i)$ i.i.d. uniform $(0,\theta)$

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, probability-limit-theorems

> Let $(U_i)$ i.i.d. uniform $(0,\theta)$ and
>   $$T_n=\left(\prod_{i=1}^{n} U_i\right)^{1/n}$$
>
> Compute the limiting distribution of the sequence $(T_n)$.

**My try:**
$$
F_{T_n}(t)
=\mathsf P(T_n \leq t)=\mathsf P\left(\left(\prod_{i=1}^{n} U_i\right)^{1/n}\leq t\right)
=\mathsf P\left(\prod_{i=1}^{n} U_i\leq t^n\right)$$
hence
$$
F_{T_n}(t)
=\mathsf P\left(\log\prod_{i=1}^n U_i\leq \log t^n\right)
=\mathsf P\left(\sum_{i=1}^n \log U_i \leq n\log t\right)
$$
that is,
$$
F_{T_n}(t)=\mathsf P\left(V_n \leq \log t\right)=F_{V_n}(\log t)
$$

where $$V_n=\frac1n\sum_{i=1}^n \log U_i$$

Since $E(\log U_1)=\log\theta-1$ and $\log U_1$ is square integrable, by the CLT, for some positive $\sigma^2$,

$$\sqrt{n}\left(V_n-(\log \theta-1\right))\stackrel{d}{\rightarrow}\mathsf N(0,\sigma^2)$$

Then

$$ \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}F_{V_n}(v)=  
\begin{cases} 
1 & v\gt \text{log }\theta -1 \\
0 & v\lt \text{log }\theta -1 \\
\end{cases} $$ 
hence
$$ \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}F_{T_n}(t)=  
\begin{cases} 
1 & t\gt \ell \\
0 & t\lt \ell \\
\end{cases} $$ 
where $$\ell=\theta e^{-1}$$
Thus, $F_{T_n}(t)\to F_T(t)$ where $P(T=\ell)=1$, at every point $t$ where $F_T$ is continuous, that is, at every point $t\ne\ell$. By a well-known theorem, this suffices to show that $T_n\to T$ in distribution, where $P(T=\ell)=1$, that is, $T_n\to\theta e^{-1}$ in distribution (hence also in probability).

Thus $T_1$, $T_2$, . . . converges to a degenerate random variable with pmf

$$f_T(t)=I_{\{\theta e^{-1}\}}(t)$$

Comment: Hint: What do you know about the limit of the random variables $$\frac1n\sum_{i=1}^n\log U_i\ ?$$

Comment: Would it be $\frac{\text{log }\theta}{2}$?

Comment: ?? Why? How? (Please be more serious addressing the question.)

Comment: Since $U_i\sim \text{uniform }(0,\theta)$ then by the CLT, this average converges to the population mean which is $\frac{0+log \theta}{2}$. Is that correct reasoning?

Comment: Two problems: First, $E(\log U_1)\ne\frac12\log\theta$. Second, the convergence of the empirical average to the mean is not run by the CLT but by the law of large numbers.

Comment: @Did I have edited my attempt.

Comment: Again some problems, I am afraid, but milder ones. 1. The invocation of $\Phi$ is wrong, you should simply delete it since it is not used afterwards. 2. Later on, we are back on tracks, it seems, but we do not know why the limit of $F_{S_n}$ is what you say. The rest is ok but you should come back to $f_S(x)$ (easy) and to the question asked, which is the convergence of $(T_n)$. So, what is this convergence, in the end?

Comment: Re your typographic troubles, try `I_{[\log\theta-1,+\infty)}(\log t)` and adapt it to other situations.

Comment: I have edited my solution. I think I have it almost right now. I am a bit confused about why the invocation of $\Phi$ is incorrect. I thought I did need it since that's how I obtained the $\frac{1}{2}$ in my cdf. What if I said instead that $F_{T_n}(t)=\mathsf P\left(\frac1n\sum_{i=1}^n \log U_i \leq \log t\right)\stackrel{\text{d}}{\longrightarrow}
\Phi\left(\sqrt{n}\left(\frac{\text{log }t-\mathsf E(\text{log }U)}{\sqrt{\mathsf {Var}(\text{log }U)}}\right)\right)$

Comment: The invocation of $\Phi$ is incorrect because $\sum\log U_i$ is not gaussian. Fortunately, it is also useless because it suffices to know that $F_{S_n}(\log t)\to0$ for every $t<t^*$ and $F_{S_n}(\log t)\to1$ for every $t>t^*$ to be sure that $S_n\to\log t^*$ in distribution.

Comment: Re the try in your last comment, note that you fall back again to a statement of the form $a_n\to b_n$, where the "limit" $b_n$ depends on $n$, which is absurd.

Comment: A general piece of advice about the site, if I may: do not get influenced too much by the votes on the answers you receive. In the present case, you accepted a deeply flawed answer (as underlined by *three* different users now), perhaps partly because it quickly received 4 upvotes. Nothing beats the careful, slow, examination, for yourself, of the validity of what is proposed to you.

Comment: I have in my notes that if $X_1$, $X_2$,... are iid random variables having finite mean and finite non-zero variance then $Z_n=\sqrt{n}\left(\frac{\bar{X}_n-\mu_x}{\sigma_x}\right)\rightarrow Z\sim N(0,1)$ so I thought it might apply for non-normal random variables. Thank you for your patience with me by the way.

Comment: Yes, the statement in your notes is correct, but not the way you (with others, unfortunately...) are suggesting to apply it. Note how the thing after the $\to$ symbol in your comment does not depend on $n$. "Thank you for your patience with me by the way" Always, towards users seemingly eager to understand and learn.

Comment: @Did I made a slight change to my post. I deleted the $\Phi$ part and included the correct way of stating the limiting distribution so it does not depend on $n$. I'm hesitant that it's okay to leave $S$ in the final pdf since we're asked to find the limiting distribution of $T$ but I'd say it's equivalent. Bringing in the $S$ confused things for me a bit.

Comment: This makes much more sense now. Thank you for all the help!

Comment: I took upon me to rewrite the end of the proof, which is simpler than what you made it to be. Revert if you do not like. As said before, all in all, the appeal to CLT is rather unnatural and the "good" argument here would use the LLN but since you insist on using the CLT... Whatever your final choice between CLT and LLN is, you now have a correct proof, which you might want to post below as an answer and even, after a while, choose as the "accepted" answer.

Comment: I much prefer this version. It is more concise and makes more sense to me than what I had.

Comment: I agree. And if you had embarked on the "LLN" way, the proof would be even better... Oops, did I already mention this point? :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**This method right here follows approximations and need to be made more rigorous as stressed out by @Chris Janjigian. Indeed the usage of the CLT below is an approximation for large $n$.**

Consider the random variable
\begin{equation}
 T = \frac{\sum \ln U_i}{n}
\end{equation}
The mean and variance of $\ln U_i$ are 
\begin{equation}
 \mu =E(\ln U)= \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f_U(u) \ln u  \ du = \frac{1}{\theta} \int_{0}^{\theta} \ln u \ du = \ln \theta - 1
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
 E(\ln^2 U)= \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f_U(u) \ln^2 u \ du = \frac{1}{\theta} \int_{0}^{\theta} \ln^2 u \ du = \ln^2 \theta - 2 \ln \theta + 2
\end{equation}
So 
\begin{equation}
 \sigma^2 = \operatorname{var}(\ln U)
 =
 E(\ln^2 U) - \mu^2
 =
 1
\end{equation}
Now
\begin{equation}
 \mathsf P\left(\frac{\sum_{i=1}^n \ln U_i}{n} \leq \ln t\right) \simeq \mathsf P \left(\sqrt{n}( T - \mu )\leq \sqrt{n}( \ln t -\mu)\right)
\end{equation}
But by the Central limit theorem, $\sqrt{n}( T - \mu ) \rightarrow N(0,\sigma^2) = N(0,1)$ So
\begin{equation}
 \mathsf P\left(\frac{\sum_{i=1}^n \ln U_i}{n} \leq \ln t\right)\simeq
 \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}
 \int_{-\infty}^{\sqrt{n}(\ln t - \mu)}
  \exp(-\frac{1}{2}x^2)
  dx
\end{equation}
Let $y = e^{x\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}+\mu}$, then $dy = \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}y dx$, we get
\begin{equation}
 \mathsf P\left(\frac{\sum_{i=1}^n \ln U_i}{n} \leq \ln t\right)\simeq
 \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}
 \int_{0}^{t}
  \exp(-\frac{1}{2}x^2)
  \frac{\sqrt{n}}{y}
  dy
\end{equation}
But $x = \sqrt{n}(\ln y - \mu)$ so we can re-arrange as 
\begin{equation}
 \mathsf P\left(\frac{\sum_{i=1}^n \ln U_i}{n} \leq \ln t\right) 
 \simeq
 \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi\frac{1}{n}}}
 \int_{0}^{t}
 \frac{1}{y}
  \exp(-\frac{1}{2\frac{1}{n}}(\ln y -\mu)^2)
  dy
\end{equation}
which is a Log-Normal distribution with mean $\ln \theta - 1$ and variance $\frac{1}{n}$.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/83866/discussion-on-answer-by-ahmad-bazzi-limiting-distribution-of-left-prod-limits).

Comment: The comments being moved to chat unfortunately made that a key piece of information disappeared, namely, that this answer is deadly wrong, falling into the classical trap of using CLT with an argument depending on $n$. IOW, the shy admission by the OP that "the usage of the CLT below is an approximation for large n" should be replaced by "the usage of the CLT below is deeply flawed".